# Installing the C compiler for LC3

Tags: c, installation, compilation, cygwin, lc3

I want to install the C compiler for the LC3. I am following this guide:

[https://users.ece.utexas.edu/~ryerraballi/ConLC3.html](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Eryerraballi/ConLC3.html)

I am on the part where it is written:

> ```
> At the command prompt (shown as $) type in (Do not type the dollar)
>       $ cd c:lc3/lcc-1.3
> to change directory to the directory that you previously downloaded the lcc software to.
> Run these three commands in order. Do not worry about warnings
>       $ ./configure --installdir /bin
>       $ make
>       $ make install
> These commands will take a few minutes to complete at the end of which you will have the software built and installed
> ```

The specific part I am having trouble with is the command:

```
$ ./configure --installdir /bin
```

When I run it this happens:

```
/cygdrive/c/lc3/lcc-1.3 
$ ./configure --installdir /bin 
Cannot locate make binary.
```

I have removed my computer name from the start.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to install `make`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much. Are you talking about running the two next commands "make" and "make install"?, because when I run them I get "-bash: make: command not found".

Comment: `make` is a program, and it seems it's not installed on your system. You must install it before running the `configure` script. The `configure` script makes sure that you have all the tools installed that you need to build, and `make` is one of the tools it checks for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much!, it worked. If you want to, you can post this as an answer and I will accept.